# Prove $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^{2017}+ x^{2015}+ 1} \geq 1$ with $x,\,y,\,z>0,\,xyz= 1$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, jensen-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Prove $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^{2017}+ x^{2015}+ 1} \geq 1$$ with $x,\,y,\,z>0,\,xyz= 1$

I try to use Jensen inequality, then:

$$f\left ( x \right )+ f\left ( y \right )+ f\left ( z \right )\geqq 3f\left (\sqrt[3]{xyz}  \right )$$

But is that true? Help me! And give some interesting solutions! Thanks!

Comment: This is not a genuine try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jensen and Karamata for the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{e^{2015t}+e^{2017t}+1}$ helps here, but it's very ugly.

I think it's better to use the following way.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}+1\right)\left(y^{2017}+y^{2015}+1\right)\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}+1\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)+2\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)+1\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)+\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)+\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)+1$$ or
$$2+\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)$$ or
$$2+\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(x^2+1\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{2017}+x^{2015}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^2),$$ which is true by Muirhead.